# Using SQL SMS How do I return a list of numbers using low and high columns

Tags: sql

I have a table SUB_Inst with columns id, low and high. How would I query the low and high numbers returning a new column with a record for each number from low to high?

```
    Current table SUB_Inst
    id  low High
    1   55  63
    2   232 234
    3   4   7
    etc.
```

Desired Results

```
    id    low    High   Num_list
    1     55     63     55
    1     55     63     56
    1     55     63     57
    1     55     63     58
    1     55     63     59
    1     55     63     60
    1     55     63     61
    1     55     63     62
    1     55     63     63
    2     232    234    232
    2     232    234    233
    2     232    234    234
    3     4      7      4
    3     4      7      5
    3     4      7      6
    3     4      7      7
    etc.
```

I tried something like this:

```
    SELECT Low, HIGH,
    (SELECT CAST(number as varchar)+','
    FROM NUMBERS
    WHERE number >= Low and number <= High 
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    FROM SUB_Inst
```

but it returned all the numbers in one field like this which won't work:

```
    Low       High             Num_List
    24   27         24,25,26,27,
    34   36         34,35,36,
    10   17         10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
    34   36         34,35,36,
    65   67         65,66,67,
    502      504        502,503,504,
    56   59         56,57,58,59,
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this :

```
SELECT id,low,high,number as Num_List
FROM SUB_Inst , NUMBERS
where low<=number and high>=number
```

Comment: This works great for what I asked! Thank you. What if I wanted to limit the results in the NUM_List field not returning a value if the same value already appears in another field for that group?